# Set maxDate on jquery ui datepicker to certain date

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I want to set the `maxDate` of jQuery UI to `18/02/2013` but upon trying, it only lets me update it to today's date.

How can I go about doing this?

```
$("#datepicker'.$row['id'].'").datepicker({
    minDate: -0, 
    dateFormat: \'dd/mm/yy\',
    maxDate: 18/02/2013
});
```

Comment: It seems you're assigning `0.004470938897168405` (18 divided by octal 2 divided by 2013) to `maxDate` instead of a date string.

Comment: Aren't you getting a syntax error or something?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: -0, maxDate: new Date(2013, 1, 18) });
```

If you want use hard coded date, use the `new Date(2013, 1, 18)` pattern.

If you want to use generic pattern, use `"+1D +1M +1Y"`.

Reference link: http://jsfiddle.net/pradkumar_n/wQe8c/

Comment: of i remove 'minDate' and use the rest, it will show 1 month ahead. for exact daet i want in 'maxDate' then i have to decrease month with 1. Other than that works great. Thanks

Comment: @JayKatira: That's because for whatever reason, the `month` parameter uses a 0-based index whereas `day` and `year` are 1-based. This is one of those _WHY?!?!_ moments.

Answer (score 5):

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( { minDate: 0, maxDate: 365 });
//365 Days
```

You can use number of days also.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20466149)

Comment: here in stackoverflow not for the result which can use directly into project use. Just  stackoverflow is using for giving spark and idea... :)

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me by setting the end date picker range from today to 7 more days.

```
$endDateCtrl.datepicker("option", "minDate", -0);
$endDateCtrl.datepicker("option", "maxDate", '+7D');
$endDateCtrl.datepicker();
```

Answer (score 1):

I am setting max date using event functions:

```
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "-9:+1",// you can define range of year here.
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        onClose: function () {

            var iMonth = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();

            var iYear = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();

            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));

        },
        beforeShow: function () {
            var selDate = $(this).val();
            if ((selDate.length) > 0) {
                iYear = selDate.substring(selDate.length - 4, selDate.length);
                iMonth = jQuery.inArray(selDate.substring(0, selDate.length - 5),

                $(this).datepicker('option', 'monthNames'));
                $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(lastYear, iMonth, 1));
                $(this).datepicker('option', 'maxDate', new Date(lastYear, 12, 1));
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(lastYear, iMonth, 1));
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $( "#dob" ).datepicker({
       maxDate: -0,
      changeMonth:true,
      changeYear:true,
      yearRange:"-100:+100",
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    });
});
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation of your code and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.