# jQuery Datepicker - Limit range to 7 WORKING days ahead (Excluding weekends)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

As the title says, I'm trying to get the jQuery Datepicker to allow the user to select dates from the next 7 working days. I've searched everywhere for a solution but the closest I've found is where the earliest date that can be selected is x days from today. I need to limit the selectable range.

So for instance if today is Monday the 1st, then I want the range to be the 2nd to the 10th because I don't want to include Saturday or Sunday.

So the the Datepicker should only allow only the 2nd(Tue), 3rd(Wed), 4th(Thu), 5th(Fri), 8th(Mon), 9th(Tue) and 10th(Wed).

Obviously these are just example dates, I'd like them for any current date.

My code is below;

```
<script>
$(function () 
    {
       var date = new Date();
       var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
       var currentDate = date.getDate();
       currentDate = currentDate;
       var currentYear = date.getFullYear();

       $('#datepicker2').datepicker(
       {
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
        minDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate)
       }); 
  });
  </script>
```

Any help would be appreciated :-)

Matt.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685913/set-maxdate-on-jquery-ui-datepicker-to-certain-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you want to know how many days you have to add to the datepicker. I did a function that calculates that amount of days depending on the day of the week.

```
function getNext7WorkingDays(){
    var d = new Date();
    var day = d.getDay();
    if(day>=0 && day<=3) return 9;
    else if(day!=6) return 10;
    else return 11;
}
```

How does it work? if today is sunday(0), monday(1), tuesday(2) or wednesday(3) you want to add 9 days. If it's thursday(4) or friday(5), 11. And if it's saturday(6), you want to add 10 days. You can do the math yourself if you want.

Then you only have to add the `beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends` parameter to your datepicker object. Also set `minDate: 1,` so you exclude "today".

Full code: http://jsfiddle.net/oyy2reuf/

```
$(function() {

  function getNext7WorkingDays(){
    var d = new Date();
    var day = d.getDay();
    if(day>=0 && day<=3) return 9;
    else if(day!=6) return 10;
    else return 11;
  }
    $("#datepicker").datepicker( { 
      minDate: 1,
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', 
      maxDate: '+'+getNext7WorkingDays()+'D',  
      beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
    });

});
```

Comment: That's a really elegant solution. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

you can use maxdate and define +x days, no need for custom javascript. Just use the functionality as is programmed

```
maxDate: '+9D'
```

for mindate use -0

```
minDate: '+1D'
```

skip weekends

```
beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
```

update fiddle from other user http://jsfiddle.net/wQe8c/914/

Comment: That doesn't consider the issue about excluding saturdays and mondays.

Comment: updated, but user already had , beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/nvj8ag3p/6/).

Define a function to add working days only to a specific date excluding weekends.

```
function addWeekdays(date, days) {
    date.setDate(date.getDate());
    var counter = 0;
        if(days > 0 ){
            while (counter < days) {
                date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1 ); // Add a day to get the date tomorrow
                var check = date.getDay(); // turns the date into a number (0 to 6)
                    if (check == 0 || check == 6) {
                        // Do nothing it's the weekend (0=Sun & 6=Sat)
                    }
                    else{
                        counter++;  // It's a weekday so increase the counter
                    }
            }
        }
    return date;
}
```

And then init the datepicker something like below:

```
$(function () {
       var date = new Date();
       var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
       var currentDate = date.getDate();
       currentDate = currentDate;
       var currentYear = date.getFullYear();
       var maxDate = addWeekdays(date, 7);

       $('#datepicker2').datepicker({
         dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
         beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
         minDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate),
         maxDate: maxDate
       }); 
  });
```

Comment: Thanks also for your easy to use solution :-)