# how to set the jQuery date picker max year limit is 3 years before of current year

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I need to display the 100 yrs from the current date but max years is current year - 3
e.g
need a years from (2017)-100. so 1917-2017(current yr) but max years is must be 2014(subtract from current year).
my code is:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="formData.cspNomineeDob" 
  placeholder="{{'com.inspirenetz.webapp.merchant.customer_form_nominee_dob_place_holder' | translate }}" 
  ng-change="age(formData.cspNomineeDob)" data-year-range="c-100" data-max-date="0" in-date-picker
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
thisyear = new Date().getFullYear()      // Get the year as yyyy
```

Then set your minDate and maxDate accordingly when you configure the widget

```
[...]

$scope.options = {
    minDate: new Date(yourdates),
    maxDate: new Date(ofchoice)
};

[...]
```

as per https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepicker .

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14685967/1971378

Reproduced from there:

> $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( { minDate: -0, maxDate: new Date(2013,
>   1,18) });

It uses minDate and maxDate options in the datepicker's configuration.

Comment: @karthickraj please feel free to upvote answer if it helped you out. Thanks : )