# datepicker disable futures dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datapicker

I would like to disable future dates (starting with the day after tomorrow) using datapicker, but it's not working. I tried 3 solutions:

```
  maxDate: 0
```

and

```
 maxDate: '0'
```

and

```
  maxDate: new Date();
```

All of them not working. Does anyone have any idea why not? Here is my code:

```
 $('#datepicker').datepicker({
   format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
   maxDate: 0
 });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set maxDate on jquery ui datepicker to certain date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685913/set-maxdate-on-jquery-ui-datepicker-to-certain-date)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using [bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). If that's the case, you should be using [`endDate`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#enddate), not `maxDate`.

If you're using another script, would be helpful adding this info to your question.

Comment: Well that probably depends on what datepicker script was used here to begin with - it’s not like there was only one.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery 3.3.1 and jQuery UI 1.12.1, this works fine:

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  maxDate: new Date()
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lmrpqv7k/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery UI, consider this:

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate

> The maximum selectable date. When set to null, there is no maximum.
>
> Multiple types supported:
>
> - **Date**: A date object containing the maximum date.
> - **Number**: A number of days from today. For example `2` represents two days from today and `-1` represents yesterday.
> - **String**: A string in the format defined by the `dateFormat` option, or a relative date. Relative dates must contain value and period pairs; valid periods are `"y"` for years, `"m"` for months, `"w"` for weeks, and `"d"` for days. For example, `"+1m +7d"` represents one month and seven days from today.

I would try the following:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
    maxDate: 2
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```